# Visual Studio for Mac Overlay Blue Screen and unable to do anything about it

Tags: macos, visual-studio, ide

I am new to the Visual Studio IDE and I am currently running the lastest version on Mac for C#.

Within a few minutes of using the IDE a random blue hue covers the entire editor and a small window of the editor overlays everything and the entire editor completely locks up.
I have to kill the process completely in order to get rid of this, only to have it crop up again a few minutes later.

Can anyone tell me how this is happening and how can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Did you figure this out?  IT happens to me multiple times a day.  It must have started with one of the prior updates because it's been fine until now.  Happens on my iMac and M1 MBA.

Comment: I get this issue regularly too, do you know if there is a bug report for it?

Comment: This still appears to be an issue. I'm on VS for Mac version 8.10.6, running on a MBP 16. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Happened to me today for first time. on Visual Studio 8.10.8 on Mac Big Sur 11.5.2

Comment: This seems to be fixed as of October, 2021. Have not had an issue since patch 8.10.11.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on my mac in Jan 2022. I am running 8.10.17.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in the Visual Studio 2022 preview.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-for-Mac-freezes/1461790

*Thanks for your feedback, this issue is fixed with the Visual Studio 2022
for Mac Preview 1 release.*